# Is uploading game cheats to YouTube an infringement upon copyrights?

Tags: copyright

Is it legal to upload videos that show how to cheat in games?

For example: Using Game Guardian or Lucky Patcher or decompiling the APK with APKTool and changing it.

I want to do that, though I think it may be a problem because cheats are kind of **against** copyrights I'm guessing.

Comment: Cheats aren't against copyright since cheating in a game does not require making a copy of it.  Posting videos of game play would possibly fall under fair use in the US, especially if the video was used in a work *about* the game, such as a review or, indeed, instructions on cheating the game.  Fair use is a US term, and similar provisions in the laws of other countries are generally more limited.

Comment: What about Israel?

Comment: Using APKTool counts as creating a copy of it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The images of the game are a [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) because they are a derivative use in which the images are incidental to the primary purpose: educating a viewer about the cheat.

Of course, a game manufacturer might still attempt to intimidate a cheat poster by suing them anyway.